# How to draw a line for matching divs with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a html project with JQuery and need to be able to allow the user to select a panel from one column to another from a different column. I know how to make the selection work but having trouble with drawing connecting lines. When the user selects the first panel, a horizontal line will connect to the middle with a circle. Then when the user selects panel2, a vertical line in the middle will move up or down (depending on where panel2 is to panel1) then draw a second horizontal line to connect panel2.

**You can see an example of the end result here**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is any JQuery library for this, but you always have the solution of svg lines. Take a look at the snippet below!

```css
.left-block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
  border:1px solid #777;
  position: absolute;
}

.right-block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 200px;
  left: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  position: absolute;
}

.circle-block {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 190px; 
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.lines {
  height: 210px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-block"></div>
<div class="right-block"></div>
<div class="circle-block"></div>

<svg class="lines">
  <line x1="104" y1="13" x2="183" y2="13" stroke="black"/>
  <line x1="193" y1="23" x2="193" y2="203" stroke="black"/>
  <line x1="193" y1="203" x2="293" y2="203" stroke="black"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: @Scott does this help you? Is it what you want?